# "if not instr" doesn't work as i thought it should in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with a list of contracts with a column for the supplier name  and one for the ending date, what I want to do is to make all passed dates red unless the contract is from a specific supplier.
I had previously used `InStr` to check if a cell had a string inside so since I have just started with vba I thought of inserting the following in my loop

```
If Not InStr(LCase(Data.Cells(i, 4).Value), "flowserve") Then
    If CDate(Data.Cells(i, "h").Value) < Date Then _
        Data.Cells(i, "h").Font.Color = -16776961
End If
```

expecting it would colour passed dates of the contracts that do not have "flowserve" in the supplier name. But instead it just seems to colour all the passed dates as if the `InStr` was not finding anything anywhere.

I then tried to do

```
If InStr(LCase(Data.Cells(i, 4).Value), "flowserve") Then
    'do nothing
Else
    If CDate(Data.Cells(i, "h").Value) < Date Then _
        Data.Cells(i, "h").Font.Color = -16776961
End If
```

and this works as I wanted, so i'm guessing that the `Not` does not work as I thought.

Now even if I kind of have a solution I was hoping that someone could explain what went wrong in the first code. Hope I was clear enough.

thanks in advance everybody!

Comment: instr gives a number as answer, not a boolean

Answer (score 12, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

InStr returns an integer not a boolean, try comparing it against the value it returns.

```
If InStr(LCase(Data.Cells(i, 4).Value), "flowserve") = 0 Then
    If CDate(Data.Cells(i, "h").Value) < Date Then _
        Data.Cells(i, "h").Font.Color = -16776961
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

you must be very careful using `Not` with `Integer` value. See the following examples:

```
Sub InStrTest()

Dim DataCellsTrue As String
Dim DataCellsFalse As String

DataCellsTrue = "flowserve"
DataCellsFalse = "haha"

Debug.Print InStr(LCase(DataCellsTrue), "flowserve") 'return 1
Debug.Print Not InStr(LCase(DataCellsTrue), "flowserve") 'return -2
Debug.Print CBool(InStr(LCase(DataCellsTrue), "flowserve")) 'return true
Debug.Print Not CBool(InStr(LCase(DataCellsTrue), "flowserve")) 'return false
Debug.Print InStr(LCase(DataCellsFalse), "flowserve") 'return 0
Debug.Print Not InStr(LCase(DataCellsFalse), "flowserve") 'return -1
Debug.Print CBool(InStr(LCase(DataCellsFalse), "flowserve")) 'return false
Debug.Print Not CBool(InStr(LCase(DataCellsFalse), "flowserve")) 'return true

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a Boolean conversion...instead:

```
If InStr(LCase(Data.Cells(i, 4).Value), "flowserve") = 0 Then
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not create your own custom function that does function like you expect it to?

```
Public Function Contains(ByVal toSearch As String, ByVal toFind As String) As Boolean
    Contains = (Instr(toSearch, toFind) <> 0)
End Function
```

Then you could say

```
If Not Contains(LCase(Data.Cells(i, 4).Value), "flowserve") Then
    If CDate(Data.Cells(i, "h").Value) < Date Then _
        Data.Cells(i, "h").Font.Color = -16776961
End If
```

and it works exactly like you wanted.

Also note that you don't have to `LCase` anything. Use the text compare option of `Instr` instead.

```
Public Function Contains(ByVal toSearch As String, ByVal toFind As String) As Boolean
    Contains = (Instr(1, toSearch, toFind, vbTextCompare) <> 0)
End Function

If Not Contains(Data.Cells(i, 4).Value, "flowserve") Then
    If CDate(Data.Cells(i, "h").Value) < Date Then _
        Data.Cells(i, "h").Font.Color = -16776961
End If
```